# Send request and response get from server - Need working code for this WSDL file in RUBY

Tags: ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

Please help me, I need code for my WSDL file for  below wsdl file url using RUBY language  parameter can be passed as pcEmployeecode...

Parameter can passed as STRING ie.,pcEmployeeCode="02385"

url ="http://online.mccolls.com.au:8080/wsa/wsa1/wsdl?targetURI=urn:OHWebServiceFMGT"

Please Refer this WSDL file and post me if you have sucess fully got the response result...

Any idea's....

I used like this, Still error hitting.

```
require 'rubygems'
#require 'soap4r'
require 'http-access2'
require 'soap/rpc/driver'
require 'soap/rpc/driver'
require 'net/http'
Net::HTTP.version_1_2
url =
"http://online.mccolls.com.au:8080/wsa/wsa1/wsdl?targetURI=urn:OHWebServiceFMGT"
soap = SOAP::RPC::Driver.new(url,"urn:OHWebServiceFMGT")
soap.wiredump_dev = STDERR
soap.options["protocol.http.ssl_config.verify_mode"] =
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
soap.add_method('getEmployeeFmgtDetails','pcEmployeeCode')
puts soap.getEmployeeFmgtDetails('02385')
```